# Perform date operations in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

My database table contains `start_time` (type `date time`) and `duration` (type `integer`, meaning hours).

I want to perform a query finding all records where `start_time + duration` is before `Time.now`.

Can I run the add operation and the comparison operation in one query? Or do I first need to read the record, convert it to rails and run the comparison there?

The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
@surveys = Survey.find_by_sql("select * from surveys where start_time  + duration < :now", :now => Time.now)
```

Comment: Date functions are database-specific. What are you using?

Comment: For example: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer, Oracle, etc...?

Comment: Thanks, actually I wanted to use the rails standard: sqlite for development, MySQL for production. Probably it makes more sense to perform the addition start_time + duration at the beginning and store it as a new value (e.g. end_time) in the table. Then I wouldn't be database-specific, right?

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a built in datetime datatype (see here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html ). How are you storing start_time in your sqlite database, and how does this compare with your MySQL database?

Comment: Thanks Mark, it is possible to create a column with type datetime in sqlite db and when I print the schema it still states it. Internally it is stored as the affinity NUMERIC. But as I understand there is no chance to run a database-unspecific operation like adding hours (read from a different column) to it.

Comment: As a side note, please label the _units_ the duration is in (As well as purpose), or you may not recall it's in hours later.  Something like `running_time_in_hours` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

technically speaking, yes you could do it the way you are doing it, however you have to use datetime functions specific to your database engine (which you didn't specify)

Comment: Agreed - pretty much every RDBMS I've seen has _slightly_ different methods for handling date/time.  May be one of the things that can't be made DB independent in your application.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using ms-sql-server, convert time into a float, it has a basis of 1.0 = 1 day.

select *
from yourTable
where (CONVERT(FLOAT,start_time)+duration/24.0) < CONVERT(FLOAT,GETDATE())

should get what you want.

Comment: -1 - not all days are 24 hours long (dependant on time zone).  I would avoid doing any similar 'math' trickery like the plague, as they allow subtle errors.